# How to repeat part of a row in a data frame

Tags: r

Here is a small example of the data frame I have:

```
data <- data.frame(station=rep(c(1,1,2),each=4), month=rep(c(2,3,2),each=4), day=rep(c(26:29),3),times=rep(c(1:4),3),place=c(1:8,1:4),V1=rep(9:12,3),V2=rep(9:12,3))
```

And this is the data frame I need:

```
data1 <- data.frame(station=rep(c(1,1,2),each=4), month=rep(c(2,3,2),each=4), day=rep(c(26:29),3),times=rep(c(1:4),3),place=c(1:8,1:4),V1=c(9,10,10,10,9:12,9,10,10,10),V2=c(9,10,10,10,9:12,9,10,10,10))
```

What I need to do is to repeat column V1 and V2 of February 28 & 29 to Feb 27th, because the original data has 300 stations and 60 years, I tried following but doesn't work:

```
data1 <- ddply(data, .(station, month, times),function(x) x[x[3:4,2]==2,6:7] <- x[2,6:7])
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: So, you want to replace the values for these dates with value of feb 27

Comment: Can you please reword. This makes no sense.

Comment: @Metrics, Yes, I only need to replace 11,12 to 10, and keep the rest the same

Comment: No, your code kept March the same which is what I wanted, but not all February needs to be replaced, only 28th and 29th, not 26th, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a "last observation carried forward" problem, and as such the `zoo` package is helpful. Set everything on the `28`th or `29`th of February as NA, and then carry forward the values from the `27`th using `na.locf`

```
library(zoo)
data[c("V1","V2")][data$day %in% c(28,29) & data$month %in% c(2),] <- NA
keyvals <- data[c("V1","V2")][data$day %in% c(27,28,29) & data$month %in% c(2),]
data[c("V1","V2")][data$day %in% c(27,28,29) & data$month %in% c(2),] <- na.locf(keyvals)
```

Result:

```
> data
   station month day times place V1 V2
1        1     2  26     1     1  9  9
2        1     2  27     2     2 10 10
3        1     2  28     3     3 10 10
4        1     2  29     4     4 10 10
5        1     3  26     1     5  9  9
6        1     3  27     2     6 10 10
7        1     3  28     3     7 11 11
8        1     3  29     4     8 12 12
9        2     2  26     1     1  9  9
10       2     2  27     2     2 10 10
11       2     2  28     3     3 10 10
12       2     2  29     4     4 10 10

> all.equal(data,data1)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do. If you have many cols, you can use `lapply` but here I don't use since you have only two cols

```
data$V1[data[,3] %in% c(28,29) & data[,2] %in% c(2) ]<-data$V1[data[,3] %in% c(27) & data[,2] %in% c(2)]
data$V2[data[,3] %in% c(28,29) & data[,2] %in% c(2) ]<-data$V2[data[,3] %in% c(27) & data[,2] %in% c(2)]
```

If you need to use multiple cols, here is the solution:

```
   do.call(cbind,lapply(data[,6:7],function (x) {x[data[,3] %in% c(28,29) & data[,2] %in% c(2) ]<-x[data[,3] %in% c(27) & data[,2] %in% c(2)]
                                               x})
          )
      V1 V2
 [1,]  9  9
 [2,] 10 10
 [3,] 10 10
 [4,] 10 10
 [5,]  9  9
 [6,] 10 10
 [7,] 11 11
 [8,] 12 12
 [9,]  9  9
[10,] 10 10
[11,] 10 10
[12,] 10 10
```

Note: Instead of data[,6:7] you can select the cols that yow want to replace, all others remain the same.

Comment: but I need the other months keep the same data, your code made March 28 & 29 replaced too. I do have 10 more columns

Comment: is there a way that you can make the output an entire data frame? because when I 'cbind' ur result with the previous 5 columns, although it worked with this small data set, the real data gets wrong combination of columns, that's why I tried "ddply(data, .(station, month, times),function(x)" in the beginning, thanks